# Xcode Auto Lay-out equivalent in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

In my free time I program in Swift in Xcode but for a school task I have to program in C# in Visual Studio. My problem is, I have some labels and text boxes that resize at runtime. But their location is not updating (obviously). In Xcode their is feature called Auto layout so you can add constraints to the labels. My question is if there is something similar in Visual Studio because my code currently looks like this:

`Label1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
Label2.Location = new Point(Label1.Location.X, Label1.Location.Y + Label1.Height + 10)`
...
And this for all the labels and text boxes on the from.
There has to be an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: is this for winforms?

Comment: wpf has a lot more dynamic control.

Comment: This is in windows forms yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the TableLayoutPanel control, or the Anchor and Dock properties...